# Pandas groupby mean mulitple columns and count single column

Tags: python, pandas, count, mean, pandas-groupby

I am scraping housing ads with BS4 and analyze the data using Pandas.

The following command,

```
madrid_rooms_district=df.groupby('district', as_index=False)['rent','size house, m2', 'price per m2','deposit'].agg(['mean', 'size'])
```

yields a table with one district per row, and the district's means for `'rent','size house, m2', 'price per m2','deposit'` per column. Which is what I need.

I also need **one** column displaying the number of ads per district, hence `'size'` in the `.agg()`. However, the current set up of the command provides me with **four** columns displaying the number of ads, one column for each item in `['rent','size house, m2', 'price per m2','deposit']`.

How can I reduce the number of "counting" columns from four to one?

E.g. I have,

```
district | rent; mean | rent; size | size house, m2; mean | size house, m2; mean | ...
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A     |    300     |     2      |        100           |       2              | ...
   B     |    400     |     6      |        200           |       6              | ...
   C     |    500     |     3      |        120           |       3              | ...
```

and I need,

```
district | rent; mean | size house, m2; mean | price per m2; mean | deposit; mean | count
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A     |    300     |        100           |        15          |       1       |   2
   B     |    400     |        200           |        14          |       2       |   6
   C     |    500     |        120           |        12          |       3       |   3
```

I've been trying to solve this differently by creating two DataFrames; one for the means and one for counting, but couldn't get them to merge into one DataFrame. Tried Series, tried joining, tried appending, tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option is to add a column of ones to the original dataset (lets call it "count"), and then sum on this column:

```
df['count'] = 1
aggregator = {'rent' : 'mean',
              'size house, m2' : 'mean',
              'price per m2': 'mean',
              'deposit' : 'mean',
              'count': 'sum'}
madrid_rooms_district = df.groupby('district', as_index=False)['rent','size house, m2', 'price per m2', 'deposit'].agg(aggregator)
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @LucSpan great to here it worked. Please mark it as the answer if you are happy with it :)

Comment: You can avoid adding a column by using "size" to get the count in the aggregator. E.g. `tips.groupby('day').agg({'tip': np.mean, 'day': np.size})`